# How to use re.search column in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

This code works for single string (inputx) but I can't get it to work when I replace it with the name of the column in my dataframe. What I want to do is split the string in column DESC where the capitalized words (at beginning of string) is place into column break2 and the remainder of the description is placed in column break3. Any assistance is appreciated.  Thanks.

Example:
[What I want output to look like (but with the different DESC from each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfMYx.png)

Code that works for hardcoded string:

```
inputx= "STOCK RECORD INQUIRY This is a system that keeps track of the positions, location and ownership of the securities that the broker holds"
pos = re.search("[a-z]", inputx[::1]).start()
Before_df['break1'] = pos
Before_df['break2'] = inputx[:(pos-1)]
Before_df['break3'] = inputx[(pos-1):]
```

But if I replace with dataframe column, I get error message:  **TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**

```
inputx = Before_df['DESC']
pos = re.search("[a-z]", inputx[::1]).start()
Before_df['break1'] = pos
Before_df['break2'] = inputx[:(pos-1)]
Before_df['break3'] = inputx[(pos-1):]
```

Comment: Have you looked into df.apply()?

Comment: I have not looked into this.  I don't know how to use it, but will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex in the df.str.split method

```
df[['result','result2','result3']] = df['yourcol'].str.split("([a-z])", expand= True)
```

If you absolutely must use re.search (which sounds a little like homework...)

```
for i in df.index:
    df.at[i, 'columnName'] = re.search("[a-z]", df.at[i, 'inputColumn'][::1]).start()
```

The reason for looping instead of using `df.apply()` is because dataframes do not like to be changed during an apply